# Populating only some columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to save some values in pandas dataframe,  but I am getting an error. What I want to do here is to save those 9 values into 5th, 6th...13th column, respectively, of the 1st (0th rather) row of pandas data frame. Other columns should remain unpopulated (for now). This is the code that I have been using:

```
e= 100
a= [6, 6]; aa= [6, 6, 6] 
b= [100, 100]; bb = [100, 150]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(e), columns=['a', 's', 'd', 'g', \
                                           'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'q', 'w',\
                                           'w', 'e', 'e', 'r','q'])

df[0, 5:13] = a[0], a[1], aa[0], aa[1], aa[2], b[0], b[1], bb[0], bb[1]
```

This is the error that I have been getting.

```
ValueError: Length of values (9) does not match length of index (100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use iloc for assignment into positional row or column indices.And use slice of 5:14 for assingnment from 5th index to 13th index (including 13th)

```
e= 100
a= [6, 6]; aa= [6, 6, 6] 
b= [100, 100]; bb = [100, 150]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(e), columns=['a', 's', 'd', 'g', \
                                           'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'q', 'w',\
                                           'w', 'e', 'e', 'r','q'])

df.iloc[0, 5:14] = a[0], a[1], aa[0], aa[1], aa[2], b[0], b[1], bb[0], bb[1]
```